# How to print new line in AT&T Assembly?

Tags: assembly, newline, att

I'm trying to print a new line character from assembly, but I can't get it to work. I read that I need to print `\n` and `\r` so `10` and `13` in ASCII, each being one byte long. Now here's what I did:

```
# \r
movl $4, %eax
movl $1, %ebx
movl $13, %ecx            
movl $1, %edx
int $0x80

# \n
movl $4, %eax
movl $1, %ebx
movl $10, %ecx           
movl $1, %edx
int $0x80
```

but it doesn't print anything and I don't know what is wrong

Comment: Syscall 4 expects a `const char*`, not a `char`. Create a byte array in your `data` section with the values `13,10`, and load its address into `%ecx`.

Comment: @Michael ok so i create array `.data array: .byte 13,10` is that right? How do i access this in `mov`? something like `movl array, %ecx`

Comment: You want the address, not the data located at that address. So it would probably be `movl $array, %ecx`